# Why is IEnumerable necessary in the view template that displays a list of movies?

Tags: asp.net-core

Why do we need to add IEnumerable in the view template that iterates through a list of model objects for example movies in asp.net core
**@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>**

Answer (score 2):

A `Movie` as @model would be just a single movie. As you want to show a list, you will have to supply one of the list types. You could use `List<Movie>`, but List implements several interfaces, such as `IEnumerable<T>` that you can use when you want just a forward-only iteration to display all.